# mysql5.5 sql_thread not running row based relay log

Tags: mysql

The master and slave are mysql5.5.60 and binlog_format=MIXED;Now it is found that the slave loses some data,But the error log is empty and show slave status status is normal；
Parse the master binlog log and slave relay log and find that the lost data still exists, but sql_thread does not apply these logs. These logs are in row based format；what is this caused by？

Comment: Are you going to show the relevant binary log contents and the table structure (`show create table`) around them? Edit the question to include them formatted (`mysqlbinlog`). Maybe its something that wasn't fixed before [5.5 EOL ~4 years ago](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is in a hurry, it has been solved by upgrading to version 5.7 on Saturday

Comment: good solution. Probably was the way to get there at the least risk.